# Equations in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I want to use LibreOffice Writer to insert equations (phonological rules) of the following kind:

[image: Example of what I mean]

[Here](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/hayes/120a/Brackets.htm) is someone's tutorial on doing this in Microsoft Word.

I've seen tutorials for including Latex in LibreOffice, though I was wondering if there is a way to include these equations via a macro or something. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [TexMaths extension](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/texmaths-1) which allows you to write equations in LATEX. (I have no experience with this extension).

In plain Libre Office Writer use Formula editor `Insert > Object > Formula Object...`

[image: firs formula]

```
left [ alignl  stack{+stop # +consonant # +alveolar } right ] rightarrow [r]
```

[image: second formula]

```
{left [ alignl  stack{+vovel # +stressed } right ] }  underline {stack{{"     "} # {} # {} }} {left [ alignl  stack{+vovel # -stressed } right ]}
```

There is workaround used for the "long underscore".

```
underline {stack{{"     "} # {} # {} }}
```

It is `stack` of 3 items (has 1 item more than stacks in the brackets) it moves underscore under the brackets. And one of its item s is string of spaces `"     "` which defines underscore length

Answer (score 0):

Click on Insert -> Oject -> Formula Object or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

[image: LibreOffice Writer Equation Editor]

Insert your eqation. There are categories you can select to insert as seen on the image below.

[image: Equations categories]